# Reloading a UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I want to load my view controller with one `navItem.rightBarButtonItem` and change it to another based on a set of circumstances. It seems as if I can only load it once, on `viewDidLoad`. Is there a method for updating a bar button item after you've changed the icon?

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    var iconOne = UIImage(named: "button")
    let buttonOne = UIBarButtonItem(image: iconOne, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "funcOne")
    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonOne

    //perform async query, if a condition holds true then:

    var iconTwo = UIImage(named: "buttonTwo")
    let buttonTwo = UIBarButtonItem(image: iconTwo, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "funcTwo")
    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonTwo
}
```

Full code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Sets custom nav bar view so we can add multiple bar buttons
        navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 44))
        navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor() // Sets bar to black
        navBar.translucent = false
        self.view.addSubview(navBar)
        navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "\(name)") // Sets title
        navBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 25)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
// Set icons
            var backIcon = UIImage(named: "backButton")
            let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backIcon, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backButton")
            navItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

            var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
            userQuery.whereKey("following", equalTo: username)
            userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    if let objects = objects {

                        for object in objects {

                            if let follower = object["follower"] as? String {
                                if follower == PFUser.currentUser()!.username! {
                                    var followingIcon = UIImage(named: "followingButton")
                                    let followingButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: followingIcon, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "unfollowUser")
                                    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem = followingButton

                                    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
                                } else {

                                    var followIcon = UIImage(named: "followButton")
                                    let followButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: followIcon, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "followUser")
                                    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem = followButton


                                    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    println(error)
                }
            })
```

Comment: Your code is working..then what's the issue?

Comment: @FrequencyMatched this doesn't work. Only `buttonOne` loads. If I try to change it to `buttonTwo` after an async function, `buttonTwo` does not load.

Comment: Can you paste the full code?

Comment: ViewDidLoad method is called once while view is loading, so you can do one thing first add button in viewDidLoad and change it as per your condition in contra method.

Comment: Yes..how can you change the button on some condition which is already executed once.

Comment: @PravinTate That's exactly the question I'm asking. I know what to do, but not how to do it.

Comment: Suppose If you want to change it on button action then in that button action you will again create new bar button and add on that before add it just nil it. I hope you will getting my point

Comment: @PravinTate Nope, I don't understand. And there's no button action to change it. I want it to load automatically after an async function is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible. So, I made my own custom view where each bar button item would be. I set my right bar button item at `var rightButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 50, 25, 30, 30))`, added an action, and added the subview to the view.